# Why don't we have a Community Wiki Section or a Community wiki tag in Questions menu for their easier access

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-wiki

There are questions with excellent answers and descriptions marked as **Community wiki**. The problem I found,

**How** to `search` and `access` them in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or for that matter in [Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/) too. (don't suggest "making it favourite" in answer, it makes Favourites list too long to search too)

I tried with **community wiki** subject in search bar, but got directed to answers with **Ubuntu-wiki** like tags.

One of the best purpose of **Community wiki** answers I found  was, that they **address & provide in-Depth solutions to common queries / questions and problems**. Which helps a lot to new-Comers like me and amateurs alike. Example questions like

[How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Although the [Votes section](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=votes) addresses them but not exclusively for all Wiki questions.

From my side I could suggest this

[image]

From the above screenshot, instead of having placed four **Meta** *(I don't know why and what for meta questions are highlighted in Ask Ubuntu page)*, we can horizontally divide it for the **Community Wiki** section with **community-wiki tags** if possible. Which will be showing two questions down below same as **Community Bulletin** section.

Or in any other way **easily accessible**.

Another feature I can suggest is **scrolling down** them to see most active or on Main-page-based question  posting idea, within the two question area, similar to Facebook right-side notification scrolling *(I hope they don't have a patent for that)*.

**P.S.**: By this, I am just suggesting a  Community-Wiki based questions format for easy accessibility. I am just trying to post my views for a better Ask Ubuntu through this. In the end, they are just personal view or suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all wiki questions by searching with [`wiki:1` set as part of the search criteria](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=). As for easy access, I don't think it's really *that* important. Contents scores are more important than if is's a community wiki or not. People don't typically come to Ask Ubuntu and hunt for questions and answers, they come from outside searches, with a search query already in mind. As a result this only helps a select few of us who are constantly on the site. So for adding it to the side bar I don't quite agree, though as I mentioned above you can easily find wiki content with the search feature.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,and  for pointing my the mistake too about **wiki:1 Search keyword** option availability . Cannot agree more ,Since it is already available , i don't see any point for my other such suggestions . ( Its the second time i ignored to explore the site , witnessed another Learning experience, Thanks ^_^ )